# Asking c preprocessor to generate code discriminating on an argument?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

*I've met my match.  I thought I could do this, but like Captain Ahab, I don't know when to call it quits.  If all else fails, I'll run a Python script to generate the code, but I'm hoping there's someone out there who is as obsessed with C preprocessor macros as I am...*

I'm using GCC.  Given a definition like this (or any syntactic changes that would simplify things):

```
// M(_slot_name, _type, _arg, _accessor)
#define DEFINE_SLOTS(M) \
  M(ENABLE_A, bool, ENABLE_A_BITPOS, registry_enable_a) \
  M(SLEEP_TIME, uint32_t, sleep_time, registry_sleep_time) \
  M(ENABLE_B, bool, ENABLE_B_BITPOS, registry_enable_b) \
  M(WAKE_TIME, uint32_t, wake_time, registry_wake_time)
```

I want the C preprocessor to expand the above into three different things.  The first one is easy (generating an enum for each `_slot_name`).  What I'm getting tripped up on is using the `_type` field to conditionally generate different output.

### 1. An enum for each slot_name:

```
typedef enum {
  ENABLE_A,
  SLEEP_TIME,
  ENABLE_B,
  WAKE_TIME,
} slot_id_t;
```

(This one is easy - I know how to do it...)

### 2. An enum that only includes the slots with a `bool` type:

```
typedef enum {
  ENABLE_A_BITPOS,
  ENABLE_B_BITPOS,
} bitpos_t;
```

### 3. Functions whose bodies differ by the `_type` field:

```
bool registry_enable_a(void) { return foo(ENABLE_A_BITPOS); }
uint32_t registry_sleep_time(void) { return bar->sleep_time); }
bool registry_enable_b(void) { return foo(ENABLE_B_BITPOS); }
uint32_t registry_wake_time(void) { return bar->wake_time); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the `_type` values are all limited to elements of a known-in-advance set and that they contain only single-token identifiers,<sup>*</sup> you can engage token pasting and some supplementary macros to achieve what you describe.  Example:

```
// M(_slot_name, _type, _arg, _accessor)
#define DEFINE_SLOTS(M) \
  M(ENABLE_A, bool, ENABLE_A_BITPOS, registry_enable_a) \
  M(SLEEP_TIME, uint32_t, sleep_time, registry_sleep_time) \
  M(ENABLE_B, bool, ENABLE_B_BITPOS, registry_enable_b) \
  M(WAKE_TIME, uint32_t, wake_time, registry_wake_time)

#define SLOT_ENUM_VALUE(_slot_name, ...) _slot_name,

#define bool_BP_ENUM_VALUE(_arg) _arg,
#define uint32_t_BP_ENUM_VALUE(_arg) /* nothing */
#define BITPOS_ENUM_VALUE(_1, _type, _arg, _4) _type ## _BP_ENUM_VALUE(_arg)

#define bool_SLOT_FUNCTION(_slot_name, _type, _arg, _accessor) \
  _type _accessor(void) { return foo(_arg); }
#define uint32_t_SLOT_FUNCTION(_slot_name, _type, _arg, _accessor) \
  _type _accessor(void) { return bar->_arg; }
#define SLOT_FUNCTION(_slot_name, _type, _arg, _accessor) \
  _type ## _SLOT_FUNCTION(_slot_name, _type, _arg, _accessor)

////////

typedef enum {
  DEFINE_SLOTS(SLOT_ENUM_VALUE)
} slot_id_t;

typedef enum {
  DEFINE_SLOTS(BITPOS_ENUM_VALUE)
} bitpos_t;

DEFINE_SLOTS(SLOT_FUNCTION)
```

The key here is that macro expansion does not provide for any conditional logic *per se*, but it does provide for treating data as code.  After all, that's what the X-macro approach you were already using does.  Combining that with token pasting can get you a lot more (wholly deterministic) variety in your macro expansions.

---

<sup>*</sup>You can use `typedef`s to provide single-token identifiers where necessary.

Comment: You have saved me from certain insanity.  I knew I'd done this before with token pasting, but the "past me" refused to give me the recipe.  Now I have it -- many thanks!

Comment: P.S.: "You can use typedefs to provide single-token identifies" -- nice touch.  Will do.